# docker load: Invalid diffID for layer

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, centos

The docker image packaging environment is Centos7+docker19
        Here is a .tar file, generated by 《docker save -o》, I need to convert it to a docker image with 《docker load -i filename》, but the process gives an error: invalid diffID for layer 9:expected "sha256....." . 
[image]
        My search on the Internet and my review of similar questions on the site guided me to consider the following points:

1. inconsistent docker environment（I have tried the following versions and it still doesn't work：13/17/18/19/20/24）
2. There is content loss during file transfer（I used sha256 to confirm that the file I received was the same as the one I executed the 《docker load》 on）
3. files have been modified during the file packaging process (I can't confirm this, but the sender of the file insists that his computer can execute the command correctly)

The source files are packaged in Centos7+docker19, my experimental device is a Centos7 environment under a Vmware 16 virtual machine

1. tested with another computer in a Vmware virtual machine environment (still with errors)
2. To avoid file changes, I tried using xftp, shared folders, compressed files and then uploads to confirm that the files I received matched the sha256 of the file used to execute 《docker load》 (still with errors)
3. change docker version, tried the following versions: 13/17/18/19/20/24 (still with errors)
4. unpack the .tar file, then fix the layer.tar where the error occurs to make sure the sha256 is the same as in the manifest.json file (the error code is changed, but a similar error occurs on more layers, invalid diffID for layer X)
5. try to use 《docker import》 and 《docker load <》 (neither works, can't run as container)